# Two locations suggestion in Profile

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-page, location

It would be good if the profile allowed both **Current Location** and then **Origin**. I don't want to be mistaken coming from another country nor I don't want also to mislead someone of my current location or where I stay for a long while.

In our profile view one of the fields is Location. In my case I am working overseas for four years now which makes me a foreign worker here. So, I put that as my location but I want also to put my origin or which exact country I came from.

Comment: To preempt - [votes on Meta are different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: Thank you for that information @Oded

Comment: Let's keep it simple. Just put in `From Origin, currently in Current Location` in the field and be done with it. There are just not enough people in that situation to justify the extra complexity IMO.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions like you @MartijnPieters and juergend but i'll be closing this question before I lose many more points lol.

Comment: @Thirdy: don't worry too much about your Meta Internet Dollars; this is how it works; you make a feature request, people that care about it either way vote on it.

Comment: There's plenty of space in your "About me" box.

Answer (score 6):

*Location* is a free text field. Put in whatever you want. Like

> Here / There
>   Currently in the USA but from Switzerland

I am in the same position right now. I am from Germany but live in Argentina. Personally I put the Country of my **current** location in there.

Comment: That's exactly what I do in my profile view.

Comment: And that is fine. Where is the problem?

Comment: It does not look nice the way I phrase it, if you happen to see my profile view.

Comment: You could phrase it differently then...